# fatal errors with optionals not making sense

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, segue, instantiation, uistoryboardsegue

I keep getting a fatal error saying how a value was unwrapped and it was nil and I don't understand how. When I instantiate a view controller with specific variables they all show up, but when I perform a segue to the exact VC, the values don't show up.

Take these functions for example...

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    
  
    
    if let displayVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.Storyboards.TeachStoryboardID) as? SchoolEventDetailsViewController {
        
        displayVC.selectedEventName = events[indexPath.row].eventName
        displayVC.selectedEventDate = documentsDate[indexPath.row].eventDate
        displayVC.selectedEventCost = documentsCost[indexPath.row].eventCost
        displayVC.selectedEventGrade = documentsGrade[indexPath.row].eventGrade
        displayVC.selectedEventDocID = documentsID[indexPath.row]?.docID
        
        navigationController?.pushViewController(displayVC, animated: true)
    }
}
```

This combined with this function :

```
func verifyInstantiation() {
    if let dateToLoad = selectedEventDate {
        dateEditableTextF.text = dateToLoad
    }
    
    if let costToLoad = selectedEventCost {
        costEditableTextF.text = costToLoad
    }
    
    if let gradesToLoad = selectedEventGrade {
        gradesEditableTextF.text = gradesToLoad
    }
    
    if let docIDtoLoad = selectedEventDocID {
        docIDUneditableTextF.text = docIDtoLoad
    }
    
    if let eventNameToLoad = selectedEventName {
        eventNameEditableTextF.text = eventNameToLoad
    }
}
```

Helps load the data perfectly, but when I try to perform a segue from a search controller the data is not there.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    navigationItem.title = selectedEventName
```

I set the title of the vc to have the event name , and I also recently added a text field to store it as well for experimental purposes (this question).

Now the issue is I want to do a data transfer from an Algolia Search Controller to that VC and I got all the other fields to show up, except for one and that was the document ID. So I created a completion handler function to get the document ID as a string and have it inserted into the vc when the segue is performed, just like how it's there when the vc is instantiated.

Here is the function :

```
func getTheEventDocID(completion: @escaping ((String?) -> ())) {
    documentListener = db.collection(Constants.Firebase.schoolCollectionName).whereField("event_name", isEqualTo: selectedEventName ?? navigationItem.title).addSnapshotListener(includeMetadataChanges: true) { (querySnapshot, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("There was an error fetching the documents: \(error)")
        } else {
            self.documentsID = querySnapshot!.documents.map { document in
                return EventDocID(docID: (document.documentID) as! String)
            }
            let fixedID = "\(self.documentsID)"
            let substrings = fixedID.dropFirst(22).dropLast(3)
            let realString = String(substrings)
            completion(realString)
        }
    }
}
```

I thought either `selectedEventName` or `navigationItem.title` would get the job done and provide the value when I used the function in the data transfer function which I will show now :

```
 //MARK: - Data Transfer From Algolia Search to School Event Details
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    
    otherVC.getTheEventDocID { (eventdocid) in
        if let id = eventdocid {
            if segue.identifier == Constants.Segues.fromSearchToSchoolEventDetails {
                let vc = segue.destination as! SchoolEventDetailsViewController
                vc.selectedEventName = self.nameTheEvent
                vc.selectedEventDate = self.dateTheEvent
                vc.selectedEventCost = self.costTheEvent
                vc.selectedEventGrade = self.gradeTheEvent
                vc.selectedEventDocID = id
            }
        }
    }
 
    
}
```

But it ends up showing nothing when a search result is clicked which is pretty upsetting, I can't understand why they're both empty values when I declared them in the `SchoolEventDetailsVC`. I tried to force unwrap `selectedEventName` and it crashes saying there's a nil value and I can't figure out why. There's actually a lot more to the question but I just tried to keep it short so people will actually attempt to read it and help since nobody ever reads the questions I post, so yeah thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `getTheEventDocID` do? If it works asynchronously, it might be that the code executes too late.

Comment: The `getTheEventDocID` gets the event document ID generated by Firebase as a String. It does work asynchronously, is there a way to prevent the code from executing too late?
@AndreasOetjen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I decided to attempt a workaround and completely ditched the `getTheEventDocID()` method because it was just causing me stress. So I decided to ditch Firebase generated document IDS and just use 10 digit generated ids from a function I made. I also figured out how to add that exact same 10 digit id in the Algolia record by just storing the random 10 digit id in a variable and using it in both places. So now instead of using a query call to grab a Firebase generated document ID and have my app crash everytime I click a search result, I basically edited the `Struct` of the Algolia record and just added an `eventDocID` property that can be used with `hits.hitSource(at: indexPath.row).eventDocID`.

And now the same way I added the other fields to the vc by segue data transfer, I can now do the same thing with my document ID because everything is matching :).

Answer (score 0):

I'm a litte confused what the `otherVC` is, which sets a property of itself in the `getTheEventDocID`, whilste in the closure you set the properties of `self`, which is a different controller. But never mind, I hope you know what you are doing.

Since `getTheEventDocID` runs asynchronously, the view will be loaded and displayed *before* the data is available. Therefore, `viewDidLoad` does not see the actual data, but something that soon will be outdated.

So, you need to inform the details view controller that new data is available, and refresh it's user interface. Something like

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    otherVC.getTheEventDocID { (eventdocid) in
        if let id = eventdocid {
            if segue.identifier == Constants.Segues.fromSearchToSchoolEventDetails {
                let vc = segue.destination as! SchoolEventDetailsViewController
                vc.selectedEventName = self.nameTheEvent
                vc.selectedEventDate = self.dateTheEvent
                vc.selectedEventCost = self.costTheEvent
                vc.selectedEventGrade = self.gradeTheEvent
                vc.selectedEventDocID = id
                vc.updateUI()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and in the destination view controller:

```
class SchoolEventDetailsViewController ... {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        updateUI()
    }

    func updateUI () {
        navigationItem.title = selectedEventName
        // and so on
    }
}
```

Comment: The `otherVC` is the vc that fetches the event details when it get's instantiated, I couldn't call the `getTheEventDocID` in the current tableVC because that vc doesn't have the information stored but I will give this a shot. @Andreas Oetjen

Comment: Yeah it still crashes with a nil error. @Andreas Oetjen

Comment: what if i put it in the viewWillAppear? would it make a difference? @Andreas Oetjen

Comment: But where does it crash exactly? In updateUI(), or before? What is the calls stack?